# Create a runtime geodatabase in QGIS for an Android app

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, android, qgis-android

I need to generate a runtime geodatabase for map visualization on my android device. Back in the days we used ArcGIS with local file-geodatabases, where we were just able to export a runtime geodatabase. Nowadays we have to use QGIS with an object-relational database and I was not able yet to find any solution to my problem. I found this [Is there a way to create a Personal Geodatabase in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33817/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-personal-geodatabase-in-qgis) , but this is already 5 years old and does not really fit my use case.

Is it possible to create a runtime geodatabase out of a QGIS project?

Or asked differently:

Is there a way to accomplish in QGIS what ArcMap can do in the picture below? [image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there a way to create a runtime geodatabase in QGIS usable on an Android device?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a portable file format storing multiple geographic datasets in a way similar to a FileGDB but possible to use with QGIS, two things come to my mind:

1. [**SpatiaLite**](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index)

> SpatiaLite is an open source library intended to extend the SQLite core to support fully fledged Spatial SQL capabilities.

2. [**GeoPackage**](http://www.geopackage.org/)

> GeoPackage is an open, standards-based, platform-independent, portable, self-describing, compact format for transferring geospatial information.

Related Questions:

- [Using GeoPackage instead of SpatiaLite, and vice-versa?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/228210/87998)
- [In what situations would SpatiaLite be selected over PostGIS, and vice versa?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/48293/87998)

Comment: I figured out how to create sth like a FileGDB format with SpatiaLite, but, in the end, this is not what I need... I tried to import the .sqlite to ArcMap and tried to run the ArcGIS Runtime Content function... it didn't work, but even if it had worked, this would mean that I always would be dependent on an ArcGIS license... I try to achieve the opposite, I want to be able to accomplish everything with QGIS

Comment: I don't know ArcMap and I don't know about "ArcGIS Runtime Content function". Maybe you should explain more in detail what you need. Because for "map visualization on Android", you can perfectly use SpatiaLite or Geopackage.

Comment: maybe a quote from http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00660000045q000000 can help express my wish : "You can consolidate the features, tabular data, basemaps, network datasets, and locators from your map into a folder and prepare it for use in applications built with ArcGIS Runtime SDKs. This folder can then be provisioned to devices to use with applications that run offline (applications that can run disconnected from ArcGIS Server or ArcGIS Online)."

Comment: Ah okay: The essential information is "applications built with ArcGIS Runtime SDKs" ;-) Sorry, then I cannot really help.